# Issue in open view controller when APNS is received in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

Hey I'm new to iPhone and I have been trying to use an Apple push notification. Basically, what I want to do is that when user clicks on the received push notification message, then i need to open a specific view controller, it is working for me. I have added custom data with key parameter "type" to my payload JSON.

here is my payload JSON :

```
{"aps":{"alert":"This is testing message","type":"Notify","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```

here is my code :

```
@synthesize viewControllerNotify;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        //Launched from push notification

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

        NSMutableString *notificationType = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"type"];

        //For redirect to the view
        if([notificationType isEqualToString:@"Notify"]){

            //Notify updates
            UpdatesViewController *uvc1 = [[UpdatesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UpdatesViewController" bundle:nil];

            self.viewControllerNotify = uvc1;
        }

        else if([notificationType isEqualToString:@"Voting"] || [notificationType isEqualToString:@"QA"]){

            //Voting & QA
            VotingQAViewController *votingQAViewController = [[VotingQAViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VotingQAViewController" bundle:nil];

            self.viewControllerNotify = votingQAViewController;
        }

        else if([notificationType isEqualToString:@"Survey"] || [notificationType isEqualToString:@"Quiz"]){

            //Survey & Quizzes
            SurveysViewController *surveysViewController = [[SurveysViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SurveysViewController" bundle:nil];

            self.viewControllerNotify = surveysViewController;
        }

        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewControllerNotify];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
        [nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    }
    else{
        //Normal Launch
        if(screenBounds.size.height == 568) {//iPhone5
            splashViewController = [[SplashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController_5" bundle:nil];
        }
        else{
            splashViewController = [[SplashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController" bundle:nil];
        }

        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:splashViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
        [nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    NSDictionary *aps = (NSDictionary *)[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    int badge = [[aps objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue];
    NSMutableString *notificationType = [aps objectForKey:@"type"];

    NSLog(@"Number of badge is = %d", badge);
    NSLog(@"notification type is = %@", notificationType);

    //For redirect to the view
    if([notificationType isEqualToString:@"Notify"]){

        //Notify updates
        UpdatesViewController *uvc1 = [[UpdatesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UpdatesViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.viewControllerNotify = uvc1;
    }

    else if([notificationType isEqualToString:@"Voting"] || [notificationType isEqualToString:@"QA"]){

        //Voting & QA
        VotingQAViewController *votingQAViewController = [[VotingQAViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VotingQAViewController" bundle:nil];

        self.viewControllerNotify = votingQAViewController;
    }

    else if([notificationType isEqualToString:@"Survey"] || [notificationType isEqualToString:@"Quiz"]){

        //Survey & Quizzes
        SurveysViewController *surveysViewController = [[SurveysViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SurveysViewController" bundle:nil];

        self.viewControllerNotify = surveysViewController;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewControllerNotify];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

My question is: Is this the correct way to redirect to the view controller when push notification is received?

Using the above code, it is redirecting to the view controller class on behalf on Notification type (custom key of notification payload json) successfully in forground and background mode but that redirected View Controller back button is not working. I don't know where i am doing wrong here. If anyone knows then please help me. Thanks.

Comment: you used in the storyboard

Comment: i am using XIB for every view controller in my App.

Answer (score 0):

The back button is not working, because you are setting the target view as a root view. You should instead construct the full navigation stack, i.e. usually, if you have a navigation view controller as a root view controller, you should create that first and then construct all the view controllers that are between the root and your leaf view.

For example, if MainViewController would be your normal start view and the back button from UpdatesViewController should lead to MainViewController you would do:

```
MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
UpdatesViewController *updatesVC = [[UpdatesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UpdatesViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navVC=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainVC];      
[navVC setViewControllers:@[mainVC, updatesVC] animated:NO];

self.window.rootViewController = navVC;
```

Comment: @TeemuThanks for your suggestion, i have made navigation view controller as a root view, but again problem is same. i am updating my question..pls check

Comment: @user2786 I edited to answer to show you push multiple views to navigation controller to get the back button working.

Comment: @TeemuI have checked with urs edited code.. but not working. I have tried alot with all solution.

Comment: Can you post the exact code and explain the navigation structure that you are trying to achieve? (E.g. if UpdatesVC is opened, which view should its back button lead to?)

Comment: @TeemuMy application have 1. Splash VC, 2.Login VC and 3, Main VC..after getting notification i need to redirect three different VC i.e updates VC, VotingQA VC and Surveys VC depends on notification-type. If user will tap on back button in all redirected VC then it will come to the Main VC.thats the main theme of my app... i have already sent you relevant code of App Delegate in my edited question. Thanks alot for giving me time..pls find my mistake so i can proceed...feel free to ask for any doubt regarding my problem.

Comment: In the edited code you are setting rootViewController of navVC to be self.viewControllerNotify and you are not creating mainViewController.

You should create mainViewController and redirected viewController (e.g. UpdatesVC) and push them *both* to  navigation controller with setViewControllers.

Comment: @TeemuI have used your above code.. then navigation bar default back button is working, but my normal VC custom back button is not working..Using [navVC setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; if i will hide then navigation back button is also hiding.. so its not working.. give me idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better You can post the notification using `NSNotificationCentre` in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and receive the notification on the other classes. So that you can push the  required view controller from the current view controller (need not to set as root view controller). Then the back button will works.

For Ex.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMesssagePushNotification object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..how i will set didReceiveRemoteNotification conditions to view controller. Are you asking for delegate from AppDelegate to other view controller?

Comment: Just pass the `userInfo` dictionary through `NSNotificationCentre` and check the condition see my updated answer.

Comment: @SurferThanks for suggestion, i have made navigation view controller as a root view, but again problem is same. i am updating my question..pls check

Answer (score 0):

There are two chances that you will access the notification data.

1. If you receive the notification when your app isn't on, then click the notification and you will get the notification data in the following function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

use

```
launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
```

to access the notification data and open the view controller you expected.

2. If you receive the notification when your app is on, but your app can be in background or foreground. If it is the former case, you will receive the notification in notification center, your app will invoke the following function after you click the notification:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

If it is the later case, you app will directly invoke the function before. And you can distinguish them using the flowing code:

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground || state == UIApplicationStateInactive){
    //notification is received when your app is in background
    //open the view controller you expected
}else if(state == UIApplicationStateActive){
    //notification is received when your app is in foreground
    //do nothing
}
```

sorry for my pool English, hope it helps~